# Criteria for search does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria

I have a problem with object criteria.

> I have 5 fields : SN(string), IP address(string), Site(string),
>   Install Date(date), End Date(date).
>  I want to be able to combine
>   fields to reduce the result.
>  For example if i have a device with
>   serial number 1234 and ip 10.4.5
>  If I search serial number 1234,
>   it return the device
>  If I search serial number 1234 and ip 10.4.5
>   it return the device
>  If I search serial number 1234 and ip 12.2.3
>   it doesn't return anything

I was able to make this filter but when there is 5 fields it's not working.
Knowing that some fields can be empty.

```
public List<IDevice> findByObject(Device device) {
    Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Device.class);

    if (device.getSerialNumber() != null && 
        device.getSerialNumber().trim().length() > 0 && 
        device.getIpAdress() != null && 
        device.getIpAdress().trim().length() > 0 && 
        device.getOwner() != null && 
        device.getOwner().getSiteName().trim().length() > 0) {

        criteria.add(Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.like("serialNumber", device.getSerialNumber()),
            Restrictions.like("installDate", device.getInstallDate()),
            Restrictions.like("ipAdress", device.getIpAdress())));

        criteria.createCriteria("owner")
            .add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions
                .like("siteName", device.getOwner().getSiteName())));
    }

    else if (device.getIpAdress() != null &&
             device.getIpAdress().trim().length() > 0 ) {

        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("ipAdress", device.getIpAdress()));
    }

    else if (device.getSerialNumber() != null &&
             device.getSerialNumber().trim().length() > 0 ) {

        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("serialNumber", device.getSerialNumber()));
    }

    else if (device.getOwner() != null && 
             device.getOwner().getSiteName() != null && 
             device.getOwner().getSiteName().trim().length() > 0) {

        criteria.createCriteria("owner")
             .add(Restrictions.like("siteName", device.getOwner().getSiteName()));
    }

    else if (device.getInstallDate() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("installDate", device.getInstallDate()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost had it correct. Take out the `else` in your `else if`

```
public List<IDevice> findByObject(Device device) {
    Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class);

    if (device.getIpAdress() != null && device.getIpAdress().trim().length() > 0 ) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("ipAdress", device.getIpAdress()));
    }
    if (device.getSerialNumber() != null && device.getSerialNumber().trim().length() > 0 ) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("serialNumber", device.getSerialNumber()));
    }
    if (device.getOwner() != null && device.getOwner().getSiteName() != null && device.getOwner().getSiteName().trim().length() > 0) {
        criteria.createCriteria("owner").add(Restrictions.like("siteName", device.getOwner().getSiteName()));
    }
            if (device.getInstallDate() != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like("installDate", device.getInstallDate()));
            }
```

that should work

Comment: The OP already asked this question yesterday. At looked at the code 15min without understanding what was going wrong. That was so simple!

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle, The issue of yesterday was resolved, and functional for two fields, then when i add some other fields, it's not working

Comment: @jmcg, thank you, it's working fine ;) I have just a problem with dates now, I will search for resolve it

Answer (score 0):

It looks that in your first if condition you have not checked condition for installDate null.